# subcaption package

Tags: lyx-layouts

How to use subcaption package? I want to fix my subfigures in the pdf. As shown in the image below, my subfigures are going out of the page. I have listened that it could be fixed with subcaption package. 
[image: These are 10 grpahs only 5 are visible]
Kindly help

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example with `\documentclass{...} ... essential packages, which you use .. `\begin{document} ... \end{document}. Normally if you put empty line after selected number of`subfloat`s, they should appear  in two lines.

Comment: are you looking for a latex code? (I don't know what lyx is)

Comment: yes... both are same i think. different versions.

Comment: @faiza please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1c}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1d}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1e}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1f}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: where should I write this code? I am not familiar with programming.

Comment: @faiza and I am not a lyx user but I think there is a `.tex` file in your work folder open it as text file and replace your old corresponding code

Comment: By putting  spaces between the images, also works...