# Arrange images as tables or subfigure or some other layout

Tags: subfloats

How to layout images like the attached picture? Should I arrange them as tables or subfigure or some other layout? Thanks.

[image]

This is my latex code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-15pt+3pt*2)/2\relax]{fish}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\halign{#\hskip3pt&#\cr
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-15pt-3pt*2)/4\relax]{fish}&
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-15pt-3pt*2)/4\relax]{fish}\cr
  \noalign{\vskip3pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-15pt-3pt*2)/4\relax]{fish}&
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-15pt-3pt*2)/4\relax]{fish}\cr
  }}}

\subfloat[]{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\halign{#\hskip3pt&#\cr
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-15pt-3pt*2)/4\relax]{fish}\cr
  \noalign{\vskip3pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-15pt-3pt*2)/4\relax]{fish}\cr
  }}}

\subfloat[]{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\halign{#\hskip3pt&#\cr
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-15pt-3pt*2)/4\relax]{fish}\cr
  \noalign{\vskip3pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-15pt-3pt*2)/4\relax]{fish}\cr
  }}}

\caption{Test images}
\end{figure}
```

The result is:

[image]

How to put "(d)" to the right of "(c)"?

**Update:**
Thank Johannes_B, subcaption is the easiest way to meet my requirement. My code is:

```
 \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.237\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_a}
        \caption{Our}\label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.237\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_b}
        \caption{Adaptive order selection}\label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.15\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_c_1}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_c_2}
        \caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.15\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_d_1}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_d_2}
        \caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.15\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_e_1}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_e_2}
        \caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome, package `subcaption` will do the job.

Comment: could you please give me some sample code ?

Comment: [subcaption package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263160)

Comment: thanks. how to make two pictures sharing one caption ? e.g. fig (c), (d), (e).

Comment: Can you add that to the questioni above (edit), along with what you got so far?

Comment: please see my pictures. I got some latex code from this website, but I can not arrange \subcaptionbox side by side ?

Comment: You somehow managed to find the most complicated code, this is not what i linked to above. Get rid of that empty line between c and d.

Comment: yes, I refer to the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/alignment-and-scaling-of-nested-subfigures. I didn't know how to use subcaption package to pack up two pictures together with sharing caption.

Comment: As always, an empty line signifies a paragraph break. This also applies inside a `figure` environment. Hence, as @Johannes_B says, remove the empty line between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost do ... Unfortunately, I haven't so nice figures to include them in MWE below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}\label{fig:fig1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}\\[2mm]
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}\label{fig:fig2}
  \end{subfigure}   

\vspace{1ex}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}\label{fig:fig3}
\end{subfigure}\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}\label{fig:fig4}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}\label{fig:fig5}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{Test images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Probably you need to make some manual tweaking of width and height of figures, that will appear as you like.

Comment: Do you have an idea, how I could "automatically" calculate the [2mm], so that the upper and the lower edge of the left image are aligned with the upper and the lower edge of the right images? (In the upper row). Or also how the images in the lower row can be aligned at the left and right edge with the images in the upper row?

Comment: This is not so complicated. One way is, that you in advance determines all widths of sub figures and  images in it.  Since you haven't give to us any information about page layout (`\textwidth` size) I wasn't able to test. Also with given relative measure you can tweak this (by trial).