# Custom Subfigures arrangements

Tags: subfloats

[image]

I have (08) pictures to be placed in one page and arranged in the format shown in the above picture. Please any help on how to deal with this.

Comment: We had something simliar yesterday: [Best way to tile images in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/698879)

Comment: Or few days ago: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288141/arrange-images-as-tables-or-subfigure-or-some-other-layout

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to have figures with the same width, it's easy with `subcaption`; I set up a quad between subfigures sharing the subcaption, and two quads between columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newlength{\subfigurewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\setlength{\subfigurewidth}{.25\dimexpr\textwidth-4em}

\centering

\begin{subfigure}{2\subfigurewidth+1em}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}%

\caption{Subtitle A}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{2\subfigurewidth+1em}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}%

\caption{Subtitle B}
\end{subfigure}

%% end of first row
\bigskip

\begin{subfigure}{2\subfigurewidth+1em}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}%

\caption{Subtitle C}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{2\subfigurewidth+1em}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}%

\caption{Subtitle D}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Title}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's how to add the tags “Initial position” and “Final position”

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newlength{\subfigurewidth}
\newcommand{\taggedincludegraphics}[3][]{%
  \begingroup\footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}\\
  #3
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\setlength{\subfigurewidth}{.25\dimexpr\textwidth-4em}

\centering

\begin{subfigure}{2\subfigurewidth+1em}
\centering

\taggedincludegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}{Initial position}%
\hfill
\taggedincludegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}{Final position}%

\caption{Subtitle A}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{2\subfigurewidth+1em}
\centering

\taggedincludegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}{Initial position}%
\hfill
\taggedincludegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}{Final position}%

\caption{Subtitle B}
\end{subfigure}

%% end of first row
\bigskip

\begin{subfigure}{2\subfigurewidth+1em}
\centering

\taggedincludegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}{Initial position}%
\hfill
\taggedincludegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}{Final position}%

\caption{Subtitle C}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{2\subfigurewidth+1em}
\centering

\taggedincludegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}{Initial position}%
\hfill
\taggedincludegraphics[width=\subfigurewidth]{example-image}{Final position}%

\caption{Subtitle D}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Title}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sir, for your reply, but I am facing another problem when trying your solution. I get this error: (! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly
(caption)                in compatibility mode.). I would like to clarify that I am using a Springer Latex template to prepare my research paper.